# Pass parameters from Router to Template's helper on Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have a router defined as follows

```
Router.route('/profile/:input',function(){
    this.render('profile');
});
```

So I can get the value of `input` calling `this.params.input`. I want to query on MongoDB for this value and pass to the template Profile. But how can I exchange this information from the Router to the helper?

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.profile.helpers({
        data: function(){
           //what to do?!
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your Template.foo.helpers, you can grab router params by:

`Router.current().params.input`